# Null Strings in Boolean expressions

Tags: java, boolean

Consider this

```
boolean askIfNotAvail = (...)
String p = locationManager.getBestProvider(c, true);
if ((p == null || p.equals("passive")) && askIfNotAvail) {
   askUserToEnableGps(false);
   return false;
}
```

1. Can I be absolutely certain that if `p == null`, `p.equals("")` will never be called (calling it would give a NPE)? I suppose whatever 'reads' this expression will jump out of the first expression `(p == null || p.equals("passive")` as soon as the first condition is met.
2. Sounds stupid, but what part of the Java language checks this expression at runtime?
3. Is there some documentation on how Java 'reads' boolean expressions like this?

Comment: You are looking for *operator precedence* and *evaluation order* in Java. Google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes you can be sure that second part of or expression will not be evaluated because Java evaluates boolean expressions lazily.
2. It is called boolean expression evaluation, see language specification.
3. Read [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid these NPEs by consequently using this syntax:

```
if ("passive".equals(p) && askIfNotAvail) {
    askUserToEnableGps(false);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. YES you can be sure if it is not called.
   if the first expression of an `||` is true the second one isn't called.
   if you explicitly want to call it use `|`

   (same way with the `&&` expression: first expression is false, the second is not excuted.
   `&` will also execute the second expression)
2. I don't know yet
3. [java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24)

Comment: @Grzegorz http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2 read it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. `p == null` is always called. If `p == null` evaluates to `true`, `p.equals("")` will not be evaluated, since `true || anything` evaluates to `true`.
2. No idea what the question is asking about.
3. Java language Spec: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/